# Is there any way to only ignore change to a checked in file in git locally?

Tags: git

There is a setup config file for our team project. 
I'm the only one who use different editor than other member, so I would need to edit the class path in that file just for myself.

Is there anyway to ignore the change to this file locally? i.e. not using .gitignore.  I tried to add it to .git/info/exclude but the change still shows up when I try to stage and commit.

There's just one line change I want to keep in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- <filepath>
```

The changes to this file will not be detected or added or committed.

To cancel the effect:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- <filepath>
```